# Error1 error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B0

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I am new in opengl and i have no idea what this error means. I am using Visual Studio 2012 > C++ > Empty Project.
I Follow these steps in other pc thats work for me but i am doing this in my pc i am getting this error.

> ### ERROR
>
> Error  1   error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2B0    ?>C:\Users\Uxi\Desktop\Sp16 \Vs\OpenglPrac\OpenglPrac\glew32.dll    1   1   >OpenglPrac

**Steps i Follow Is :**

1. Copy the Folder Glew and Glut from My folder to your desktop.
2. Open Visual Studio , Select New Project
3. Select Visual C++, Select Empty Project
4. Write OpenGLProject as the name of your project.
5. Right click on your project in solution explorer and select add -> add new item.
6. Select C++ .cpp item , Name it HelloOpenGL.
7. Right Click on your Project again, select properties
8. Select all configuration in configuration dropdown list
9. Go to C/ C++ -> General
10. Go to Additional Include Directories
11. Click on the button on right side and select Edit then select glew/include folder
12. Click on the button on right side and select Edit then select glut/include folder
13. Press OK
14. Now Go to Linker - > Input
15. Go to Additional Dependencies
16. Click on Edit and Right glew32.lib and freeglut.lib.
17. Press OK
18. Now go to General
19. Go to Additional libraries Directories
20. Go to the Glew folder and select lib
21. Go to the freeglut folder and select lib..

ThankYou.

Comment: Make sure that you have linked against `glew32.lib` and not against `glew32.dll`. Normally this error occurs when linking against a dll instead of the lib and the error message also says `glew32.dll` (which should normally not be part of the linking process at all).

Comment: Hi thank you bdl.
I mistakenly wrote glew32.dll in link insist of glew32.lib now i compile the project no error occurs but my build is hang in OpenglPrac.vcxproj -> .

Comment: What do you mean by hang? Does it simply stop somewhere during the build? What does the output window show?

Comment: yes its freezes in build . no output generates. i know it is tool set problem but its not showing for win-xp option.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The error message suggests, that you have linked against `glew32.dll` instead of `glew32.lib`. One always has to link against the lib file and copy the dll to a place where it can be found at runtime.

Comment: Dear @BDL, I did the same way but during building,  It gives "The code execution cannot proceed ***.dll was not found. Reinstalling the problem may fix this problem".

My **.lib is located in include folder, the .dll one is located in bin.

C/C++ ->I have added both include and bil folders.
Linker -> General ->I have added both include and bil folders.
Linker -> Input -> Linked only ***.lib